# Prevent page life cycle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have a master page with a logout link on it.  When the user clicks the link I call the following method:

```
    private void Logout()
    {
        SessionBll.DeleteSessionEntry(this.sessionId);
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Roles.DeleteCookie();
        LogHelper.Location = string.Empty;

        LogHelper.Info(logger, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, 
           MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "User has been logged out from 
                Administrator.Master", LogMessage.LoggedOut);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
```

Now, when a user is on a page and they click the link, the normal page cycle happens and this method is called.

The **problem** with this is that the user shouldn't have to wait for the page cycle, they should be taken to the logout page as fast as possible (as long as it takes to run the logout method on the server).

How do I skip the page life cycle, yet still call this method?

Thanks.

Comment: As a side-note, if you don't want to experience the ASP.NET web forms page lifcycle, then I'd suggest you look at ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: You can't prevent some things from happening. If you really want to call Logout as soon as possible, do it by overriding `OnInit` and then just call `Response.End()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't skip the page life cycle; what you can do instead is this:

Change that `logout` link to a normal link (`<a href="...">`) and on `Page_Load` of the `Login` page, execute that code you posted but only `if(!IsPostBack)`

**Edit**

If your Login page needs to know (as you put it) when to execute your cleanup code; you can pass a parameter on the logout link as so:

```
<a href="Login.aspx?Logout=y" > Logout </a>
```

And then check on Page_Load:

```
if (!IsPostBack &&  Request.QueryString["Logout"]=="Y" )
{
   //Your code here
}
```

This is super fast.

Comment: Not sure if I understand yet.  How would the Login page know if it is suppose to call the Logout method?  This page is currently used to log the user in, not out.

Comment: @subt13: Well, if it `needs to know` (as you put it) you can pass a parameter on that link (i.e. `<a href='Login.aspx?Logout="y"' ...>` and then check that `Request.QueryString["Logout"]=="Y"` on `Page_Load` so that you know for sure that you can call your cleanup code.

Comment: @subt13: Edited my answer. Take a look. I think it's very clear now.

Comment: that makes more sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a possibility of infinite redirect here because of RedirectToLoginPage call?

Comment: @subt13: No, because `RedirectToLoginPage` will only redirect to `Login.aspx` without any URL Parameters called "Logout"

Comment: I think this is going to work the best in my scenario, since I use a separate logout.aspx page for a different purpose.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem with this is that the user shouldn't have to wait for the page cycle

I would argue that the problem is that the page is apparently doing *too much* in the page cycle.  In WebForms, the page cycle happens.  It's just how it works.  Consider this...

- In order to interact with the code-behind, the client-side form needs to POST to the page.
- In order to handle the POST, the page needs to exist in memory.
- In order to exist, the page needs to go through its standard creation steps in its life cycle.

Without seeing any actual code, my gut reaction is that you're doing too much on `Page_Load`.  Refactor it out.  Only do what you need to do to *load* the *page*.  Not to process data, not to do all kinds of back-end work, just load the page.  This should be a fairly light process.  Then logically plug in your necessary background work where appropriate.  (In WebForms, and this is a major pet peeve of mine, this often ends up as wrapping a lot of stuff in a conditional to check `IsPostBack`.)

Now, there *is* something you can do.  Based on your question, it sounds like what you want to skip is the loading of the *current* page, and instead go straight to the logout page.  Depending on your setup, you have a couple of approaches:

- Make the logout link nothing more than a simple link.  That way the browser will only request the logout page, as opposed to making a form POST to the current page (as it does with, say, a button or a `LinkButton`).
- If the logout page actually needs some kind of value POSTed to it, make it its own HTML `form` with the action set to the logout page.  This involves relying less on the server-side drag-and-drop controls and more on just crafting some simple HTML (which is always a good thing to be able to do in web development).

Or, thinking about your question a bit more, are you asking how to make the logout page skip the Master Page's cycle?  If the logout page uses the Master Page, then it can't skip it.  The page has to exist before it can be used.  But you *can* create a standalone logout page without a Master Page which does nothing more than process the logout (and then redirect, I suppose, to another page).  This would process the logout quickly, but overall still require that a page be loaded somewhere.  Which brings us back to the point that the **problem** is that the page takes too long to load, not that you're loading a page.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  This master page is used by many content pages.  Each content page's page_preinit/init/load/etc will have various logic in it, so some pages take longer to load than others.  I think it is an oversimplification to believe that it is possible to just reduce/change the codes in these event for every content page.  FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(); sends the user to the Login Page (not the logout page).  So are you saying to move the Logout method to a new page called (e.g. Logout.aspx) and then putting a link on that page that calls the Logout method

Comment: @subt13: It's not at all an oversimplification.  If the application was designed with logic in the wrong places then it would indeed be a significant effort to fix it.  But putting logic in the right places in the first place is not at all unheard of.  As for the logout page, you can indeed have a standalone page which performs the logout.  Perhaps an empty page with no Master Page which performs the `Logout()` functionality on `Page_Load`, resulting in a redirect to the login page.  This would skip the step of re-loading the _current_ page to perform a logout.

Comment: In some of the content pages, I need to access the database before page_load to do dynamic control creation.  There is no other place to do some logic, so I'm not going to go back on that (and using !IsPostBack can not always be used).  In that case, you and Tomislav are saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use something that doesn't have the lifecycle - ASP.NET MVC as someone suggested or create an .ashx (handler): `logout.ashx` would simply log out the logged-in user.  That would work without having to change frameworks.

This is not often done, though, usually you'd use a different page, which would still have a full lifecycle (as per Icarus' answer).

Comment: I like your idea of ashx.  Changing frameworks for this one-off case doesn't make sense though.

Comment: Adding an .ashx isn't changing frameworks, btw, they were the two separate ideas (just clearing that up) :)

Answer (score 1):

Call entirely different page that would only perform Logout task an no other relevant code. That way, you don't have to worry about page life cycle.