# How to stop LoginStatus ctrl on MasterPage causing default page to reload

Tags: asp.net

I have a loginstatus control on my master page. No matter what action I chose to implement on logout clicking, the page contained within the master page is reloaded/refreshed before logoff is completed. The logoff and loggingoff events both fire after the reload so I can't about the refresh there.

How can I abort the reloading of the page contained within the masterpage?

Comment: I think you may be experiencing this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8671089/345490 (take a look at the accepted answer)

Comment: I did search before posting my question - honestly. Yes, it does help me to find a solution. Thanks.